# Accessing instance object from mocked method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to test a function that creates and transforms a dataframe. At the end of the function the dataframe is saved as a csv. Is there a way to "hook" into the function and retrieve the end state of the dataframe? I tried to mock the `to_csv` method at the very end of the function but I can't figure out how to retrieve the dataframe instance from that call.

I know that I could:

- Read the resulting csv and verify it that way but I'd prefer not to because the runner of these tests has an unpredictable file system.
- Return the dataframe, however, my actual function is used in airflow which doesn't allow dataframes to be passed around

Here's a stripped down runnable example:

`foo.py`:

```py
import pandas as pd

def bar():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
    # assume df is transformed in some way
    df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

`test.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, call
from foo import bar

class TestBar(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("pandas.DataFrame.to_csv")
    def test_bar(self, mock_to_csv):        
        bar()

        # How do I access df?
        self.assertEqual(mock_to_csv.mock_calls, [call('test.csv')])
```

Comment: How about adding an optional parameter to `bar()` so that it can be passed a file-like object, which if supplied is given to `to_csv` in place of the filename? Then the test can create a `StringIO` object, pass it to the function, and inspect what is written into that object.

Answer (score 0):

I thank you for that beautiful minimal runnable example.

Surely the criticism here is that the function bar() is not very testable, right? I mean, wouldn’t you like to reactor bar so it returns df?
If that’s infeasible either assign to a module level global on the way out, or make “bar” a private helper which the real function trivially calls.

Or more ambitiously, refactor so it accepts df, even if only as an optional argument. That sort of DI would offer you maximum flexibility.
Then the target code logic would look like “df = df or …”

The high level concern is that a complex function doesn’t get to hoard all its data and side effects as private. As a non-functional requirement, it absolutely must expose such details so they’re accessible to a test suite.